# asp.net mvc Kendo Grid confirmation dialog before the update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a confirmation dialog before updating a record in the DB. So I included `.Events(e => e.Save("onSave"))`.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<VIEWMODEL>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Description);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit();                                   
        });

    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id(mr => mr.Id);
        })
        .Update(upd => upd.Action("Action", "Controller"))
    )
    .Events(e => e.Save("onSave"))
)

<script>
    function onSave(e) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        $('#confirmDialog').data("kendoDialog").setOptions({
            title: "Edit Confirmation",
            content: "Are you sure you want to edit this Item ?"
        });
        $('#confirmDialog').data("kendoDialog").open();
    }

    function confirmEdit(e) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var tr = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr");        
        $('#confirmDialog').data("kendoDialog").close();
    }

    function cancelEdit(e) {
        $('#confirmDialog').data("kendoDialog").close();
    }

</script>
```

**Confirmation Dialog**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Dialog()
    .Name("confirmDialog")
    .Modal(true)
    .Visible(false)
    .Actions(a =>
    {
        a.Add().Text("No").Action("cancelEdit");
        a.Add().Text("Yes").Action("confirmEdit").Primary(true);
    })
)
```

However, this confirmation appears after saving the values. How do I make this appear before saving to DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Save` event, you need to call `e.preventDefault` to prevent the save from taking place. More information here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/save

Something like this:

```
function onSave(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent save from taking place

    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    $('#confirmDialog').data("kendoDialog").setOptions({
        title: "Edit Confirmation",
        content: "Are you sure you want to edit this Item ?"
    });
    $('#confirmDialog').data("kendoDialog").open();
}
```

Now, you will need to do a bit more work to actually perform the save if the user confirms the save. One way would be to call `sync` on the grid datasource in your `confirmEdit` function. Something along what is detailed here: https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-save-event. (not putting code here since this wasn't part of your question)

A different, possibly simpler, approach may be to use a confirm dialog directly in your `onSave` function and only call `preventDefault()` when the user cancels in the dialog, that way you don't have to call `sync` on the datasource when the user confirms, you can just let the save happen. This would look something like this:

```
function onSave(e) {
    // kendo confirm info https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/confirm
    kendo.confirm("Are you sure you want to edit this Item?")
        .done(function() {
            console.log("User accepted");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("User rejected");
            e.preventDefault(); // cancel save
        });
}
```